# Continuing script from where an error occurred inside a for loop

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I have a code that writes and formats data into google sheets like so:

```
sheet = client.open("google_sheet")
cats = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

for cat in cats:
    ws = sheet.worksheet(cat)
    for cell in all_columns:

        ws.update_cell(50, cell.col, f"=('A5 / 1.2) * (1 - A14)")  # dummy formula
        # ...
        ws.update_cell(14, cell.col, f"=('C5 / 1.2) * (1 - G14)")  # dummy formula # 50
```

So in general I have a google sheet with multiple sheets in it to which I write `dataframes` and then using `gspread` module I change cell values / formatting and I am constantly getting `API error for too many write requests per minute`. I tried adding `time.sleep(x)` here and there but this does not help me. I thought of using `try / except` but in this structure I have, when I would get the `error`, `continue` statement would then run all `ws.update_cell` functions from the very top because all of those updates are happening in a single loop.

I would not want to do something like this:

```
for cat in cats:
    ws = sheet.worksheet(cat)
    for cell in all_columns:
        try:
            ws.update_cell(50, cell.col, f"=('A5 / 1.2) * (1 - A14)")  # dummy formula # 1
        except API error:
            time.sleep(60)
            ws.update_cell(50, cell.col, f"=('A5 / 1.2) * (1 - A14)")  # dummy formula # 1

        try:
            ws.update_cell(50, cell.col, f"=('A5 / 1.2) * (1 - A14)")  # dummy formula # 2
        except API error:
            time.sleep(60)
            ws.update_cell(50, cell.col, f"=('A5 / 1.2) * (1 - A14)")  # dummy formula # 2

        # ...
        ws.update_cell(14, cell.col, f"=('C5 / 1.2) * (1 - G14)")  # dummy formula # 50
```

Which I don't believe is the best practice. I thought of writing a function that would have the `try / except` in it but each of the `ws.update_cell` formulas are unique.

So I don't know what is the best practice for a problem `when an error occurs in a for loop, wait 60 seconds then try the same thing again` for a non unique update statements inside a for loop.

Comment: I thought that in your situation, those formulas can be put using one API call. But before I think of the sample script, I have 2 questions in your script. 1. In your script, what is `'` of `'A5` in `=('A5 / 1.2) * (1 - A14)`? 2. Are you using 2 kinds of formulas like `=('A5 / 1.2) * (1 - A14)` and `=('C5 / 1.2) * (1 - G14)`? If you are using other formulas, can I ask you about them?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, 1 - thats a typo, sorry. 2 - currently I am iterating through columns and rows in google sheets and depending on which row I am in I assign a different formula for a row. And depending which column I am in - the formula changes, so there are very little formulas that are the same.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the logic for creating each formula you want to put?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is twofold. Even if all the formulas were really different and there seems to be no *apparent* way to simplify them, you could always write a function that takes in the differences between your formulas from the parameters, that you must specify elsewhere, like in a big list. There is of course no better way to simplify this if the formulas are genuinely very different.

Once you have done that, do not repeat the code but put everything into a while True loop that will break (going to the next formula) only if the action succeeded. Of course there is a risk to be stuck in the loop by doing this without any max retries limit.

```
def function(num,formula):
    ws.update_cell(num, cell.col, formula)

your_functions=[
    [50,f"=('A5 / 1.2) * (1 - A14)"],
    #...
    [14,f"=('C5 / 1.2) * (1 - G14)"]
]

for num,formula in your_functions:
    while True:
        try:
            function(num,formula)
        except:
            #eventual sleep here
            continue
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is create a super class of the gspread client.

Then you override the `request` method there you can handle your time sleep etc without touching a line of you application code.

Have a look at the [client](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/effe1fdd93bcb2ce8c9f6a17b393ecc6877143be/tests/conftest.py#L56) used in the test suite for `gspread` it does exactly that.